# Neo4j foreach and reduce are not helping

Tags: neo4j

I am working on a company's data which provides services in a way where every service request has an ID and involved parties in it, every involved party can either one of two roles role one is service provider role two is service requester I am mapping this data in a way that every node has two List properties, Property one containing all service request IDs this node is involved in and the other List property is the given nodes role for every specific request ID (either service provider or requester).

**example****: Node1 requested service X this request had ID 1 Node2 and Node3 responded to request ID 1 as providers to service X**

in Node1's List property ID's first element ID1 is saved and requester in first element of List property Role same happens for Node2 and 3 where ID1 is saved in their first element of List property ID and provider in saved in first element of Role List property so eventually to get parties involved in service request ID1 can use this code

**match (n:Client) where n.id[0]='1' and n.Role[0]='Requester'
with n
match (m:Client) where m.id[0]=n.id[0] and m.Role[0]='Provider'
return n,m**

this works well for a single service request But I want do this for millions of requests so I need to iterate over each n.Nodes(requesters) IDs  saved ,get every ID value's position in the List then searching corresponding List properties Location in m.Nodes(providers) using the same position to match the same ID with role(Provider) as every node can have many IDs and Roles I tried using reduce and foreach but I failed to find what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a more graph-oriented data model. The use of list properties for your use case is extremely complex and inefficient, as you have come to realize.

Here is an example of a data model that is much better suited to a graph database. The data model has a `Service` node for each requested service, and a `Party` node for each party that either provided or requested a service. A party has a `PROVIDED` relationship to each service it provided, and a `REQUESTED` relationship to each one it requested.

The following Cypher query creates the nodes and relationships that match your sample scenario:

```
CREATE
  (p1:Party {id: 123}), (p2:Party {id: 234}), (p3:Party {id: 345}),
  (s1:Service {id: 10057}),
  (p1)-[:REQUESTED]->(s1),
  (p2)-[:PROVIDED]->(s1),
  (p3)-[:PROVIDED]->(s1)
```

The following Cypher query returns a list of the requester(s) and a list of any provider(s) of the service with the `id` value 10057:

```
MATCH (r:Party)-[:REQUESTED]->(s:Service {id: 10057})
OPTIONAL MATCH (p:Party)-[:PROVIDED]->(s)
RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT r) AS requesters, COLLECT(DISTINCT p) AS providers;
```

With this data model (and assuming you have a reasonable amount of data), you should also have an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.3/cypher/schema/index/#schema-index-create-a-single-property-index) (or [uniqueness constraint](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.3/cypher/schema/constraints/#constraints-create-unique-constraint)) on `:Service(id)` to make the `MATCH` clause more efficient.